# Condensing jQuery function

Tags: jquery

So, I have following jQuery (Ajax).

```
jQuery("button1").click(function(){
    jQuery("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
});
jQuery("button2").click(function(){
    jQuery("#div2").load("demo_test.txt");
});
jQuery("button3").click(function(){
    jQuery("#div3").load("demo_test.txt");
});
jQuery("button4").click(function(){
    jQuery("#div4").load("demo_test.txt");
});
jQuery("button5").click(function(){
    jQuery("#div5").load("demo_test.txt");
});
```

As you can see, I have 5 buttons and 5 divs.

Is there a way to minify this jQuery functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your *divs* have different purposes and so they need to be different.

There are many ways to achieve this. One would be using a `for`, but it is not usually a good practice like for these cases.

You could otherway make the buttons to belong to the same class, and then select the *div* according to a related (for example [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)) element of `$(this)`. You are not posting your **html** code, so I will assume your *div* *contains* your button.

**JS**

```
jQuery(".mybtnclass").click(function(){
    var mydiv = $(this).parent('div');
    jQuery(mydiv).load("demo_test.txt");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <button class="mybtnclass" value="click me1" />
</div>

<div>
   <button class="mybtnclass" value="click me2" />
</div>
```

This would target the container *div* and overwrite it's contents, thus removing the clicked button.

---

Another (sintactically more complex) approach is to target the div by an element's **id**, using the **[data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** html attributes, and the *div* can me anywhere in your *document*, not necessarily containing the button.

**JS**

```
jQuery(".mybtnclass").click(function(){
    var mydiv = $(this).data('banner');
    jQuery('#'+mydiv).load("demo_test.txt");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="mybtnclass" value="click me1" data-banner="banner1" />
<div id="banner1"></div>

<button class="mybtnclass" value="click me2" data-banner="justanothername" />
<div id="justanothername"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the 'Attribute Starts With' selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) that checks for names starting with "button".

There is a list of all of jQuery's selectors [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Something like this would could do what you're asking. There's probably a more elegant way to do it.

```
jQuery("button[name^='button']").click(function(){
    var lastChar = this.name.substr(this.name.length - 1);
    $("#div"+lastChar).text("Clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

?? yes there is

```
for (var i=1;i<6;i++) {
  jQuery("button"+i).click(function(){
    jQuery("#div"+i).load("demo_test.txt");
  });
}
```

but this is probably not what you are looking for. Please elaborate the question.